# get element binding inside structural directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a structural directive that converts a **Select** to **label** if the array that populates select options has only one item. 
This array could be an array of objects or array of string. I'm wondering if it is possible to fetch the binding inside the directive

```
<select  *convertToText="deltas" >
   <option [value]="" [selected]="true"> - Select  -</option>
   <option *ngFor="let delta of deltas" [value]="delta">
     {{delta.type | formatType}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to get the output of "delta.type | formatType" in the directive? the pipe may is optional. If the array is String, the binding would be just {{delta}}

This is how my directive looks like

```
@Input() set convertToText(options: Array<any>) {
  if(options.length > 1 ) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  } else {
    this.viewContainer.remove();
    let compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(OptionTextComponent);
    let component = this.viewContainer.createComponent(compFactory);
    component.instance.optionValue = options[0];
  }
}
```

If there is an alternate approach, please provide me some directions
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an other alternative: you can create a component that take the list as input and render either a select or a label using *ngIf or *ngSwitch.

Comment: That is what we are doing now. Since we have quite few of these, it would be better to have a directive to do the rendering logic.